# Currency Symbol problem in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to customize a money field. 
My goal is to achieve this format:  -55,555 LEKE

But when I try to customize the currency symbol CR automatically removes the space between my price and the currency symbol (-55,555LEKE). I don't like this format. I tried everything.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for the delay, but your "crystal-reports-xi" tag isn't often used. Otherwise, someone might have answered this sooner).

1. Go into the **Custom Style** menu of your field.
2. Under **Currency Symbol**, choose **Enable Currency Symbol** and **Fixed**.
3. Change the **position** to `-123$`
4. Close the menu and **left-align** the field.

Now, all your currency symbols will be on the far right side of your field and the currency will be on the left.  This isn't *exactly* what you're asking for, I know, but it's pretty close.

Alternatively,

1. Remove the currency symbol from your field entirely.
2. Make a text object with the currency symbol inside it.
3. Put the text object to the right of your currency field.

If you want to right-align your field *and* have that space between the symbol and the currency, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're using to design the report, but in Visual Studio, it's possible to achieve this by modifying the CurrencySymbol property in the property list or setting it programmatically.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using VS with Crystal reports and I was having the same problem as caisenm - writing a space just didn't work. But if I set the CurrencySymbol in the property list it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Format Field > Number > Customize >Currency symbol   -> click on the 'x+2'
and type the following:

```
totext (' '&'LEKE').
```

in the field between the apostrophes-- `'  '&` type as many spaces as you require.
Then save.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.
I'd tried the first method you suggested, but it hadn't looked so pretty.

```
-123                                                                 LEKE
```

But I realized that this problem does not exist in older versions. So I put the currency symbol with Crystal Reports 7, and opened the document with Crystal Reports 11 and completed my design ;) But you should not enter the currency settings after opening with 11 or it swallows the space immediately.